# firebase wrap auth in functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Can I wrap auth, federated and email based in functions?
I need to add an attribute of appId to the user on creation. I can't use the functions api - onUserCreate because it needs to be done on creation. The user is created with a certain appId - we should be able to have the same user for different appIds.
I don't want to do it on the client side.
I want to be able to call functions- create user and to send appId.

Comment: Also posted on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/oQNbXyii53M.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks. I will link future questions. Would you be able to direct me to an optional solution? Is my question clear?